# CSS container width on wrapped elements

Tags: html, css, containers, width

I'm trying to get a container div to expand to wrap around several inline-block elements.

Everything works until the container shrinks or I add more elements.

```css
.top {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
}
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is an example. https://jsfiddle.net/8fhjaf6z/11/

The gray .container wraps the boxes inside of it until you either add more boxes or shrink the .top container. At that point the boxes wrap and move to the next line which is what I want but now the gray `.container` fills the red `.top` container leaving a bunch of empty space to the right.

I've tried floating the `.box` elements as well, but get the same results.

Comment: do u want to show red color in the space left to the right ??

Comment: Yes that is correct. If the box elements do not exceed the width of the .top container then the gray container wraps all of the box elements as intended.  However, once you add more box elements and they exceed the width of the .top container the box elements wrap down to the next row but now the gray container fills the entire width of the .top container vs. just wrapping the the box elements.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way to fill the space created by the boxes that moved to the next line is to set `.container`'s display to inline. Now you have the gray background only behind the boxes. With a top padding you can than make the gray background take the full height of the boxes (as a workaround for setting a height to an inline element, which is not possible with the height attribute):

```css
.top {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: red;
  font-size: 0;
}
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline;
  padding: 105px 0 0 0;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner.  I tested this and it sort of fixed my problem.  I guess what I would really be looking for is a solution where the gray container extends down below the three boxes on the right and leaves the red space on the right.  Where as now when the boxes wrap to the next row the gray container fills the entire .top container.   Maybe this is intended behavior.  I was just trying to understand the logic behind why it acts like that and if there is a way to get the result I was looking for.